# Angular how to wait for an http observable to emit

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

I'm doing a http request to the backend and it takes some times until I get a response. It's returning an observable. Is there any possibility in the .subscribe() to wait until there is an emitted value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you pass to `subscribe` (or, better option, the operators you put in the `pipe`) is **only** called when the Observable emits.